# JUnit What is the best way to fail java.io.File.delete() for unit testing

Tags: java, file, unit-testing, junit, io

I am unit testing a method that is using [java.io.File.delete()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#delete()) and I am wondering what the best way to make [java.io.File.delete()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#delete()) fail is.

```
final File newFile = new File(filePath); // filePath is a valid path

if (newFile.exists())
{
    if (!newFile.delete())
    {
        final String msg = "Error deleting file " + newFile.getAbsolutePath();
        LOG.error(msg);
    }
}
```

So the file must exist, and I want the [newFile.delete()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#delete()) to fail.

I understand this could be done by:

- Mocking the [File](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) class delete method to return false or throw [java.lang.SecurityException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/SecurityException.html)
- Somehow use a security manager and its [SecurityManager.checkDelete(java.lang.String)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/SecurityManager.html#checkDelete(java.lang.String)) method denies delete access to the file
- Maybe simply changing read/write access alone could do this, but it hasn't seem to be working for me in [JUnit 4](https://junit.org/junit4/).

Comment: Use mockito (or similar) to mock the file. Or choose `filePath` to point to something you can't delete (e.g. `/dev/null`).

Comment: The file point to something that exists though.

Comment: your code is tightly coupled to implementation concerns. Consider abstracting the IO access so that it can be easier to mock and maintain. Just because you can mock `File` with Mokito doesn't mean that you should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of options which come to mind.  These depend on the circumstances of your method (do you pass the `File` instance to the method?  Is the name of the file predictable?)

- If you pass the `File` instance to the method, you can simply mock it with mockito.
- If you don't pass the `File` instance to the method, you can use PowerMockito's `whenNew` to return a mocked instance when the `new File` part is called.
- If you know ahead of time what the filename will be; most OSes will stop you deleting the `File` simply by having an open handle to it.  For example, in your test have:

  ```
  try (new FileInputStream(new File(predictableFileName))) {
      myThing.methodToTest();
  }
  ```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Mockito, here is an example test:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    final File file = mock(File.class);
    when(file.exists()).thenReturn(true);
    doThrow(new SecurityException("fail")).when(file).delete();

    if (file.exists()) {
        file.delete(); //throws java.lang.SecurityException: fail
    }
}
```

But I see that the `new File` is part of your method under test? Then, one solution (which is not too pretty) is to extract the line where the File is created to a package-local method, and then stub it out.

```
public class SomeClass {
    public void someMethod(final String path) {
        final File file = createFile(path);

        if (newFile.exists()) {
            if (!newFile.delete()) {
                final String msg = "Error deleting file " + newFile.getAbsolutePath();
                LOG.error(msg);
            }
        }
    }

    File createFile(final String path) {
        return new File(path);
    }
}
```

Then test like this:

```
public class SomeClassTest {
    private SomeClass someClass;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        someClass = spy(new SomeClass());
    }

    @Test
    public void someTest() {
        final File file = mock(File.class);
        doReturn(file).when(someClass).createFile("path");
        //set up behaviour of mocked File            

        someClass.someMethod("path");
        //verify and whatnot
    }
}
```

Comment: Couldn't I use PowerMockito.whenNew to get around the new? My class is slightly more complicated than this and now I'm wondering if theres another way to do it besides mocking if the whenNew isn't simpler. How can I force the security exception on the file that exists?

Comment: I have introduced PowerMockito to a project once, and ended up regretting it. It's powerful and all, but when you first get an error from it, you really have no other choice but to ignore the test, since the error message is related to byte code. Also, the whole use of PowerMockito is a code smell. It just shouldn't be necessary if your code is decently structured (with a few exceptions, like the one above.)

Answer (score 1):

The best way... is way relative to each one's opinion.

This depends a lot on what you want to test, from what I saw, I would most probably have multiple tests, but one of them would surely be lock the file by opening a stream to it and let the normal behaviour send the exception.

But as I said, this depends a lot on each one's opinion